# Redbeanphp - Getting data from foreign key index

Tags: php, redbean

Sorry for the vague title, if anyone would like to edit it to reflect more about what I am posting, please do so.  Here is the situation.  I have 3 tables:

support:

> id | contact_id | title | problem | etc

supportlogin:

> id | contact_id | login | pass | etc

contact:

> id | first_name | last_name | email | etc

I am loading the support bean just fine, and am accessing the contact info:

```
$support=R::load('support',1);
echo $support->contact->first_name;
```

I want to echo the supportlogin information similarly:

```
echo $support->contact->ownSupportlogin->login;
```

Is this possible, and am I doing it the right way?  I have tried the following ways with no success:

```
echo $support->contact->supportlogin->login;
echo $support->contact->ownSupportlogin->login;
echo $support->contact->ownSupportlogin[0]->login;
```

**EDIT: MORE INFO**
I did `print_r($support->contact)` and was given the data:

```
RedBean_OODBBean Object
(
    [null:RedBean_OODBBean:private] => 
    [properties:RedBean_OODBBean:private] => Array
        (
            [id] => 109
            [phone] => 1234580970
            [first_name] => Tim
            [last_name] => Withers
        )

    [__info:RedBean_OODBBean:private] => Array
        (
            [type] => contact
            [sys.id] => id
            [tainted] => 
        )

    [beanHelper:RedBean_OODBBean:private] => RedBean_BeanHelperFacade Object
        (
        )

    [fetchType:RedBean_OODBBean:private] => 
)
```

And then I did `print_r($support->contact->ownSupportlogin)` and this showed up:

```
Array
(
    [13] => RedBean_OODBBean Object
        (
            [null:RedBean_OODBBean:private] => 
            [properties:RedBean_OODBBean:private] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 13
                    [link] => fecd4ef67e8c789efa1792f9ee0efff4
                    [login] => 
                    [password] => 
                    [receiveemails] => 1
                    [contact_id] => 109
                    [role] => 1
                )

            [__info:RedBean_OODBBean:private] => Array
                (
                    [type] => supportlogin
                    [sys.id] => id
                    [tainted] => 
                )

            [beanHelper:RedBean_OODBBean:private] => RedBean_BeanHelperFacade Object
                (
                )

            [fetchType:RedBean_OODBBean:private] => 
        )

)
```

I can access it using: `echo $support->contact->ownSupportlogin[13]->login;`, but doing it dynamically seems to be a problem....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out, and will leave it up in case anyone else has a similar problem:

This will only work if you have a 1:1 relationship.  Redbean populates the `ownSupportlogin` as an array of all supportlogin rows related to the contact. If one table can have many child tables, then you will need to loop through that array and pull out the data you want.  If it is a 1:1 relationship, then you can use PHP's `reset()` to access the data of the first element in the array:

```
echo reset($support->contact->ownSupporlogin)->login;
```

Comment: Since `print_r()` and `var_dump()` output is almost impossible to read for humans in this case, let me just mention that **simple supportlogin elements go through can be achieved simply be doing this:**
`foreach($support->contact->ownSupportlogin as $supportlogin) echo $supportlogin->login.'<br/>';`